# SQL: Sum Largest N Values by unique ID

Tags: sql-server-2005, group-by, sum

I have a table that populates with a unique id and points

I would like to sum the largest 5 values for each distinct unique id within a resultset.

For example:

I would like the following resultset...

```
UPN             Points
A308204201057   40
A308204201057   46
A308204201057   40
A308204201057   40
A308204201057   40
A308204201057   46
A308204201057   46
A308204201057   40
A308204201057   46
A308208401097   40
A308208401097   46
A308208401097   46
A308208401097   40
A308208401097   52
A308208401097   46
A308208401097   46
A308208401097   46
A881233002009   40
A881233002009   40
A881233002009   46
A881233002009   34
A881233002009   22
A881233002009   40
A881233002009   34
A881233002009   40
A881235002017   22
A881235002017   34
A881235002017   40
A881235002017   46
A881235002017   46
A881235002017   46
A881235002017   46
A881235002017   40
```

To populate as...

```
UPN             Points
A308204201057   224
A308208401097   236
A881233002009   206
A881235002017   224
```

I can order them by points descending and select the top 5 values and I can group the UPNs and total them fine, but I can't figure out how to group the UPNs, but only total the 5 largest values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE + `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT UPN, Points, 
         RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UPN 
                                 ORDER BY Points DESC)
  FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT UPN, SumTop5Points = SUM(Points)
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= 5
GROUP BY UPN
ORDER BY SumTop5Points DESC
```

<kbd>[**Demo-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/93f89/5/0)</kbd>

Result:

```
UPN             SUMPOINTS
A308208401097   236
A308204201057   224
A881235002017   224
A881233002009   206
```

Answer (score 0):

something like the following should do the trick for you

```
WITH TableCTE AS(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UPN ORDER BY Points) AS RowNumber,
       UPN,
       Points
    FROM    TABLENAME
 ) 

SELECT    UPN,
    SUM(Points)
FROM    TableCTE
WHERE    RowNumber <= 5
GROUP BY UPN;
```

check this blog [select top n rows from a table](http://itworksonmymachine.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/select-top-n-rows-from-a-table-for-each-group/)